# Protection of mongoDB config file - mongod.cfg

Tags: c#, mongodb, security

How to protect the configuration file (mongod.cfg) when an APP runs in the same PC of the MongoDB server.

I have an application in C# that I want to connect into a mongoDb server via connectionstrings.

I modified the security of my mongod.cfg to accept authentication, and I created an admin user and another one to readwrite database 'X'.

But now, if someone has access to my config file and change the security to disabled, all the information of the databases are available.

How can I protect my config file?

Comment: If someone has config to your file he probably can uninstall mongodb, so your problem is non-existent. What you can do is restrict folders by right, obviously mongodb is root priveleged, and you client is just simple user which has no access to mongodb.

Comment: The problem is not to have access on the folder, is to have the possibility to change the security parameter, inside of the mongod.cfg,  and after that, see all the information inside of the databases. No one knows a method, for example, to encrypt the config file?

Comment: If one can ecnrypt file, one can also decrypt file. Encryption and decryption is usefull in system where secret is secure, in your case you just make things overcomplicated for yourself whereas applying folder/file/service permissions is as easy as invoking console command. Hacking of system permission is faaar more complicated task than decryption, and faaar more easier to manage/apply, even by non-developers and simple users, you can even audit those permission for further security breach research, which of course more valuable than saying "I encrypted things, it will never be hacked".